# Estimating departures in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, time, transition

I'm attempting to estimate how many individuals (unique "id"s) that were in a given zone in a given time step (date), departed that zone in the following time step. Here is a tiny subset of the data:

```
zone   date            id
802 2007-01-01       453444
803 2007-01-01       407680
803 2007-01-01       415786
804 2007-02-01       407680
802 2007-02-01       453444
802 2007-03-01       415786
804 2007-03-01       407680
802 2007-04-01       415786
802 2007-04-01       407680
804 2007-04-01       453444
801 2007-05-01       453444
804 2007-05-01       407680
804 2007-05-01       415786
804 2007-06-01       453444
801 2007-06-01       415786
804 2007-06-01       407680
803 2007-07-01       407680
803 2007-07-01       453444
804 2007-07-01       415786
```

So my question is, how can I estimate these departures? I am trying to create a matrix that will look something like below for the number of individuals that departed summed per date/zone. Any help you can offer is very much appreciated.

```
        zone   2005-07-01   2005-08-01   2005-09-01 
1       103          0          1          0      
2       106          0          0          3        
3       107          0          0          0       
4      1603          0          0          0        
5      1607          0          0          0        
6      2204          0          0          0         
7      2206          0          3          1       
8      2209          0          0          0        
9      3106          0          0          0         
10     3804          0          0          0         
11     3806          0          0          0
```

I'm thinking something like a two step function that 1.) iterates through all individual IDs asking if zone[i] in date[t] = zone[i] in date[t+1], and if NOT yield a "1" and store in a matrix (indicating departure); then 2.) summing all the the 1's for each zone/date across all IDs to yield the sum of departures per zone for each time step. Something like that, but having trouble formulating that function

Comment: Your data are messy: the id "415786" is reported to be in zones 802 and 804 the same day (2007-04-01). How do you want to handle that?

Comment: The duplicates were my error. Sorry! See the next comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New answer:**

So, the **first step** is to group the data by `id` and `zone`, and to count the number of departures at each time. This can done with:

```
all.dates = data.frame(date=unique(zz$date))
n=nrow(all.dates)

bool.list = by(data=zz, INDICES=list(zz$zone, zz$id), FUN=function(x){
  xx = merge(x,all.dates,by=c('date'),all=T)
  xx$id[is.na(xx$id)] = 0
  return(diff(xx$id)<0)
  })
```

which returns a list indicating the departures:

```
> bool.list
: 801
: 407680
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: 802
: 407680
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: 803
: 407680
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: 804
: 407680
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: 801
: 415786
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[...]
```

This list can easily be converted to a matrix:

```
tmp = matrix(unlist(bool.list),ncol=nrow(all.dates)-1,byrow=T)
colnames(tmp) = all.dates$date[2:nrow(all.dates)]
rownames(tmp) = rep(rownames(bool.list), length(colnames(bool.list)))
```

Returning:

```
> tmp
    2007-02-01 2007-03-01 2007-04-01 2007-05-01 2007-06-01 2007-07-01
801      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
802      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE
803       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
804      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE
801      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE
802      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE
803       TRUE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
804      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
801      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
802      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
803      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
804      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE       TRUE
```

The **second step** is to collapse all rows with the same id and to count the number of `TRUE` values. This can be done with:

```
result = aggregate(tmp,list(rownames(tmp)),FUN=sum)
```

Returning:

```
> result
  Group.1 2007-02-01 2007-03-01 2007-04-01 2007-05-01 2007-06-01 2007-07-01
1     801          0          0          1          0          1          1
2     802          0          1          0          2          0          0
3     803          2          0          1          0          0          0
4     804          0          1          0          1          1          2
```

which should be the desired answer.

---

**Old answer:**

Here is my best guess, provided that you did not specify how to handle duplicated data:

```
# we extract all the dates:
# they will define the number of columns of the returned matrix 
all.dates = data.frame(date=unique(zz$date))

bool.list = by(data=zz, INDICES=list(zz$id), FUN=function(x){
  if (any(duplicated(x$date))) {
    x = x[!duplicated(x$date),]
  }
  # we complete so we have all dates represented, for each ID and each zone
  xx = merge(x,all.dates,all=T)
  return(diff(xx$zone)==0)
}
)

# we build the matrix from the list vectors
r = matrix(unlist(tst),ncol=nrow(all.dates)-1,nrow=length(names(tst)),byrow=T)

# some cosmetic job
colnames(r) = all.dates$date[2:nrow(all.dates)]
rownames(r) = names(bool.list)
```

This returns, for your example:

```
> r
       2007-02-01 2007-03-01 2007-04-01 2007-05-01 2007-06-01 2007-07-01
407680      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
415786         NA         NA      FALSE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE
453444       TRUE         NA         NA      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
```

You may want to replace the NA with whatever value makes sense to you (`TRUE` or `FALSE`)

Notice the part:

```
  if (any(duplicated(x$date))) {
    x = x[!duplicated(x$date),]
  }
```

This is where I get rid of the second zone data for the same `date` and the same `id`, if duplicated. You may want to modify this to have another way to handling messy data :)

Comment: Jealie, Thanks so much for the help. The duplicated data was my error. The actual data has no duplicates like that. I was trying to replicate a much smaller version of what the data might look like and apparently was sloppy in my replication. I appreciate your efforts! I am confused though because this function is not returning the correct information. I need a function that iterates through all ids and tells me how many unique ids that were in zone x at time t left zone x in t+1. Sorry I wasn't more clear. The actual data has 25 zones, 80 time periods and 61 ids. Does that help clear it up?

Comment: Oops, my bad, I mis-understood your question.. I will try to see if I can change my answer to make it work for your problem

Comment: My question was poorly worded. I greatly appreciate all your help! Let me know if there is a way for a newbie like me to up vote you in some way.

Comment: I'm thinking something like a two step function that 1.) iterates through all individual IDs asking if zone[i] in date[t] = zone[i] in date[t+1], and if NOT yield a "1" and store in a matrix (indicating departure); then 2.) summing all the the 1's for each zone/date across all IDs to yield the sum of departures per zone for each time step. Something like that, but having trouble formulating that function.

Comment: Yop, this is the right way to do it. I will update the answer shortly, and if it does the job you can accept it :)

Comment: That's about it. The dates might be off by one day/month, if this is the case it is quite easy to fix it :)

Comment: That answer is fantastic and very elegant! I was working all day on how to do this and am embarrassed to show you the incomplete mess I produced. Thanks so much! One more thing, when I run the "rownames(tmp) = rep(rownames(bool.list), length(colnames(bool.list)))" line, I get: "Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("103", "106", "107", "801", "802",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent". Not sure why, but maybe it's something simple that I'm overlooking. It clearly ran for you. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you like it :) This answer works fine on the dataset you provided (with zones from "801" until "804"). Maybe I overlooked something, or maybe the whole dataset has some inconsistencies?